# Implement Android Wear Phone Accept/Reject

Tags: android, wear-os, phone-call

Android Wear and the Phone app have terrific incoming call handling, with the face of the person calling and easy way to accept/reject the call.

How is this implemented, is there a way to implement it for a VOIP app?